# Conditional JSON Query of Google Sheets Based on html value

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I'm attempting to conditionally pull data from Google Sheets via javascript where "gsx$team" = something written (preferably from a drop-down, but I also can't seem to get that to work in Visual Studio Code for some reason.)

Any tips?

Current Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      let draft1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   draft1.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).feed.entry;
   
       let i;
       for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         let pick = data[i]["gsx$pick"]["$t"];
         let pos = data[i]["gsx$pr"]["$t"];
         let player = data[i]["gsx$player"]["$t"];
         let team = data[i]["gsx$team"]["$t"];

   
        document.getElementById("draft1").innerHTML +=
           "<tr>" +
           "<td>" +
           pick +
           "</td>" +
           "<td>" +
           pos +
           "</td>" +
           "<td>" +
           player +
           "</td>" +
           "</tr>";
       }
     }
   };
   
   draft1.open(
     "GET",
     "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1muELUgnZUfR6Z31nlpeZhBb4a4d_yRrbar5n9JBpuFY/2/public/values?alt=json",
     true
   );
   draft1.send();
       
       </script>
```

Current HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-wrap" style="max-width:100%;overflow:auto;"><table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="homepagemodule">      
      <tbody id="draft1">
      <tr>
                 <th>Pick</th>
                  <th>Pos</th>
                  <th>Player</th>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
          </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by getting it to work in visual studio code? What is your setup? Do you mean you can't get a live server to work?

Comment: The drop down doesn't seem to function in VSC, but I'm not too worried about that part right now.

Comment: I don't understand, if you are not too worried about that part, what part are you worried about?